# A sufficient and necessary condition of independent increments?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $X$ be a stochastic process. Is that independent increments equivalent to $X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}(s)$ for every $s<t$, where $\left\lbrace\mathscr{F}(s):s\geq 0\right\rbrace$ is the natural filtration? Which statement is stronger? Any counter-example?

Comment: yes, they are equivalent.